# How to export data with its header in larave (maatwebsite)?

Tags: excel, laravel

So I am using this command to export my single Product Detail. While Exporting I want to export Header too. So I how can I export both data and data header?

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel
```

In product (index.blade.php)

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <tr>{{$product->name}}</tr>
        <tr>{{$product->price}}</tr> 
        <tr><a href="{{route('prodcutExport',$product->id)}}">Export Product Detail</></tr>
@endforeach
```

In ProductController.php

```
 public function export()
    {
    
    $products = Product::where('id',1)->get();    
    return Excel::download(new ProductExport($products), 'patient.xlsx');
   }
```

In ProductExport.php

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Product;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class ProductExport implements FromCollection
{
  
    public function __construct($products)
    {
        $this->products = $products;
     }


    public function collection() 
    {
        return $this->products;
    }
  
    public function headings()  //How can i export this
    {
        return [
          'Name','Price','Colour','Created At'
          ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the whole `ProductExport` class code please.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki yes i have shown my full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `WithHeadings` to your Class:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Product;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class ProductExport implements FromQuery, WithHeadings
{  
    public function __construct($products)
    {
        $this->products = $products;
     }


    public function collection() 
    {
        return $this->products;
    }
  
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
          'Name','Price','Colour','Created At'
          ]
    }
}
```

Comment: and ?
what for this ?     public function headings() ..it show error in this

Comment: That must add the "Headings" to the exported data. isn't that what you need ?

Comment: if you donot mind. can you give small exmaple please ?

Comment: yes,I donot know why it show error on public function headings(){}.
It say return type declaration must be compatible  with withHeadings()->headings():array

Comment: Try with `public function headings(): array` see the updated code.

Comment: No ReaderType or WriterType could be detected. Make sure you either pass a valid extension to the filename or pass an explicit type.